# Apache redirect http://%{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}/%{REQUEST_URI} to https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to redirect

```
<VirtualHost *:5555>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =5555
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I attempt to connect to via a web browser it is adding an extra `/` inbetween the `%{HTTP_HOST}//%{REQUEST_URI}`

How do I remove the extra / between the values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About mod\_rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: There's nothing in what you've posted that would cause this double slash, so the problem would seem to be _something else_. What other directives do you have? Any application redirects? Check the network traffic - maybe there are multiple redirects? What URL are you requesting?

Answer (score 1):

> If the [`Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is used within a `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` section with the `URL-path` omitted, then the URL parameter will be interpreted using expression syntax.
>
> This syntax is available in Apache 2.4.19 and later

This makes this, once again, a case of [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html).

```
<VirtualHost *:5555>
    <Location />
        Redirect permanent https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: However, the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (the value of the `Host` HTTP request header) also includes the port number (if present on the request), so this would redirect to the same port, not port 80 as would seem to be the intention? (Although the same issue would affect the OPs code as well, but neither would the OPs code result in a double slash, so I suspect there is something else going on here?)

Comment: But also... when "the URL parameter is interpreted using expression syntax" is the source URL-path still appended to the target? I would think that would/could conflict with the "expression syntax"? The docs aren't clear, except for the similar case with the `Alias` directive, where the source URL-path is _dropped_ (mapping to a single URL, as defined using the _expression syntax_). (There is a new directive `AliasPreservePath` in later version 2.5.1 that preserves the URL-path with regards to the `Alias` directive, default `Off`. Nothing similar for the `Redirect` directive though AFAICS.)

Comment: Ah, with regards to my first comment... since the redirect is to `https` (port 443 by default, not port 80 as I mentioned) then that may resolve the issue? (Although I'm not convinced it would?)

Comment: Haven't got time to test this. Is there a variable without the port number? Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: "Is there a variable without the port number?" - Unfortunately not. You would normally need to extract the hostname less the port number using a regex and `RewriteCond` directive, but then you are back to using mod_rewrite. I'm not sure how that could be written in expression-syntax suitable for a `Redirect` directive? (_Aside:_ I wonder if a general solution is really necessary and the hostname could simply be hardcoded?)

Comment: Furthermore, I wonder why is this even wanted in the first place, because who would land on `http://example.com:5555` anyway.

Comment: Redirect can specify a path, no need to use Location, this is bad advice.

Comment: Path is required for using the *expression syntax*, as explained in the answer.

Comment: _Typo:_ "Path is required for using the expression syntax" - Should be "`<Location>` is required for using the expression syntax". This is neither good or "bad", it's simply the required syntax. @DanielFerradal

Answer (score 0):

No need to check the port or if it is SSL, if a requests that is SSL lands here you will get an error since virtualhost won't be able to answer, and virtualhost is already specifying it is port 5555 the port this virtualhost is answering too, so you those redundand directives are not necessary.

If you insist on using mod rewrite and using variables this would be the most simple/correct way.

```
<VirtualHost *:5555>
    ServerName normallyouwantahostnamehere.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

If you know the hostname I would be inclined to define it correctly and use a simple redirect (which redirects everything without the need to capture):

```
<VirtualHost *:5555>
    ServerName hostname.example.com
    Redirect / https://hostname.example.com/
</VirtualHost
```

Comment: As mentioned in [my comment on @Esa's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1147440/apache-redirect-http-http-hostserver-port-request-uri-to-https-h/1147483?noredirect=1#comment1497927_1147483), "the `HTTP_HOST` server variable also includes the port number (if present on the request)", so your `RewriteRule` would redirect back to port 5555, not port 443, which is presumably the intention.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're trying to redirect HTTP requests on port 5555 to HTTPS without an extra slash between the `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}`. You can achieve this by modifying your `RewriteRule` slightly.

Here's the updated configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:5555>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =5555
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The key change here is in the `RewriteRule`. By using `^` before `https://%{HTTP_HOST}`, it anchors the rule to the beginning of the URL, ensuring that there won't be an extra slash inserted.

With this modification, the redirect should work without the extra slash between `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Let us know if this works, or if you're still having problems!

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense. You are simply changing the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (that matches against the requested URL-path) from `(.*)` to `^`, which will make no difference at all in this context. "By using `^` before `https://%{HTTP_HOST}`, it anchors the rule to the beginning of the URL" - no it doesn't. The `^` simply asserts the start-of-string, which will be successful for everything (every URL-path). Whereas `(.*)` matches everything (and unnecessarily captures everything - the backreference is not used), so the result of `^` and `(.*)` is the same in this context.